# Xamarin Android Client in real device fail to connect with C++ socket server

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets, xamarin

I have a android client need to communicate with a C++ socket server running on my computer. I have successfully connected the client with the the server using android emulator on my computer. However, when I try to run the app on my real device, it cannot connect. The code on the android client side is:

```
 Int32 port = 5037;//Is this port setting matters? 

IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("128.101.251.176");//Am I setting the IP address correct?

IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port); 

Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 

sock.Connect(ipe);     //always stuck at this line
```

My android device IPV4 address is 128.101.252.96 and my computer IPV4 address is 128.101.251.176. Is this means My computer and android phone is in the same LAN? How should I setup my IP address? And also do I need to make any change on my Server side? Thank you!

Comment: You are in different subnets, 251 and 252, you will not connect...

Comment: @Coroner_Rex: Could you show your solution to fix this problem? I got this problem, too. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MrNeo Like Gusman said it cannot find each because the router has allocated computer and the real device into different subnets. You can use your computer to build a wireless LAN by yourself inside of using the public wifi and home router sometimes also puts devices into different subnets so you should always build the LAN by yourself.

Comment: Thank you ^^. My problem fixed, too!